# Why does Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision not work with my L.GeoJSON?

Tags: javascript, text, leaflet, collision-detection

Trying to use the plugin `"Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision.js"`. I can't see what the error is as it is supposed to hide text when there is a collision. All text is showing but still collide into each other and looks pretty messy on the map.

What can be wrong in the below sample? I have tried to follow the instructions as good as possible but there seems to be something missing!

```
var point_txt = new L.layerGroup();

function filt_point(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.size === "villages") return true;
}

var collisionLayer = L.LayerGroup.collision({ margin: 8 });

$.getJSON("/data/city_villages.geojson", function(json) {
  var pointLayer = L.geoJSON.collision(null, {
    filter: filt_point,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      label = String(('<span class="textLabelclassmall">' + feature.properties.Namn + '</span>');
      return new L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: createLabelIcon("textLabelclasssmall", label)
      });
    }
  });

  var createLabelIcon = function(labelClass, labelText) {
    return L.divIcon({
      className: labelClass,
      html: labelText
    });
  };

  pointLayer.addData(json);

  collisionLayer.addLayer(pointLayer);
  collisionLayer.addTo(point_txt);
});
```

style.css:

```
.textLabelclassmall{
left: 1px;
top: -10px;
background-color: transparent;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
white-space:nowrap;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 0.5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of `Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision` expects the layers added to itself to be `L.Markers`, and not instances of `L.LayerGroup` (or instances of derived classes such as `L.GeoJSON`) - it is simply not prepared for that use case.

Add the individual markers as they are being created, or consider using `L.GeoJSON.Collision` instead.

Comment: my apologies but could you give me more hints like how the above code should have been written, i tried with changing to `pointLayer = L.GeoJSON.Collision (null...` but that did not work...

Comment: Actually it does work to certain extent, but still there are lots of collision text, after changing to `.Collision` and looked more carefully. But it is not close to the demo site that works great. I'm looking for similar effect.... might add that I'm not using any background or border around the text in CSS. I did test and remove in the demo with developer tools and seems still to work, should not be a problem then I guess....

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a solution by using `background-colour`in style.css with transparent and use `<span>`tag for the label in the js code above. I have updated to the working solution for the code above.